# Mock private method with new object creation

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito

I've written a class which reads the entire file and returns the content.

```
class ClassToTest {
    public methodToTest(String input) {
       return privateMethod(input);
    }

    private privateMethod(input) {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(input);
        IOUtils.toString(classPathResource.getFile());
    }
}
```

Now, inside my test class, I don't want my test to actually read the file from so I'm trying to mock the method `classPathResource.getFile()` but somehow I'm not able to do so without writing `PrepareForTests()` and if I do that those test are not counted in JaCoCo.

I've written test case as

```
@Test
public void test_methodToTest() {
     mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
     when(IOUtils.toString(any()).thenReturn("DUMMY_STRING");
     methodToTesT("file1.txt");
     ...
}
```

The problem is `IOUtils.toString` gets mocked properly but the call `classPathResource.getFile()` tries to access the file on the disk. For this, I can do this

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassPathResource.class)
            .withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedClassPath);
```

And add annotation to my test class as

```
@PrepareForTest(ClassToTest.class)
class MyTestClass {
... 
}
```

But now the problem is this test class is skipped from the JACOCO test coverage . How can I write tests for this class?

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that includes your test - it seems you're asking about how to test but that's the part you're not showing

Comment: A `ClassPathResource` should be injected into `ClassToTest` instead of `ClassPathResource` creating it's own instance.  Then to test, inject a mock.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewS My problem requires the ClassPathResource to be created dynamically based upon the parameter passed. So I can't inject it as it's not class variable. Instead it is private variable in private method.

Comment: Since `ClassPathResource` requires a constructor parameter, consider injecting a simple Factory to create an instance of a `ClassPathResource`.  The Factory can then be easily mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a mocked reference into the constructor doing this:

```
class ClassToTest {
    private ClassPathResource classPathResource;

    public ClassToTest(ClassPathResource classPathResource) {
        this.classPathResource = classPathResource;
    }

    public methodToTest(String input) {
        IOUtils.toString(classPathResource.getFile(input));
    }
}
```

Or you can pass the mocked reference into the method doing this:

```
class ClassToTest {
    public methodToTest(ClassPathResource classPathResource) {
        IOUtils.toString(classPathResource.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't pass the object as a constructor parameter. Each time method is invoked different file is read. Also, I can't mock entire `CassToTest` it would make the testing invalid as I'm trying to test the same class.

Comment: You can read a different file inside the method `getFile`, you don't need a new instance for that. You don't have to mock `ClassToTest`, you have the references that it contains

Comment: I, actually, don't want to read anything from disk as this will incur some delay in running all these test cases.

Comment: That's why you have to mock `ClassPathResource`

Comment: Only way I can do that is by running `@PrepareForTest(ClassToTest.class)` which neglects the test coverage for this files in JaCoCo test coverage reports.

Answer (score 0):

Having to mock a private member should be seen as a code smell and an indication that something is wrong with the current design. Because `ClassPathResource` is being initialized internal to the subject class it is now tightly coupled to that class. While not entirely impossible to mock it does make testing the class cleanly more difficult. Consider inverting the creation of the class to a delegate as a dependency.

```
public interface PathResource {
    String getFile(String input);
}
```

This will allow the injection of the dependency

```
class ClassToTest {
    private classPathResource;

    public ClassToTest (PathResource resource) {
        this.classPathResource = resource;
    }

    public String methodToTest(String input) {
        return privateMethod(input);
    }

    private String privateMethod(String input) {
        return IOUtils.toString(classPathResource.getFile(input));
    }
}
```

and the dependency can be mocked/faked/stubbed when testing.

```
public void Test() {
    //Arrange
    //mock creation     
    PathResource resource = mock(PathResource.class); 
    String input = "path";
    String expected = "expected_output";
    //stubbing
    when(resource.getFile(input)).thenReturn(expected);

    ClassToTest subject = new ClassToTest(resource);

    //Act
    String actual = subject.methodToTest(input);

    //Assert
    verify(resource).getFile(input);
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

in production code the `ClassPathResource` would be derived from the abstraction

```
public class ClassPathResource implements PathResource {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

and it would be associated with the abstraction at the composition root.

Following the above suggestions would now allow `ClassToTest` to be tested in isolation without any knock on effects of implementation concerns.

Comment: The parameter for the `methodToTest` can be passed as a different value for the same object instance. Also, would it make sense to change the code just because we can't test it?